# Variable not changing value on checkbox condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This section uses a checkbox to select your extras, once selected you move onto the next step and it will display your choice in a header called `checkout[itemname]`. When a check box is selected it changes a variable from `false` to `true` however my code doesn't seem to be doing that.

I will show an example section of the user selecting "Neck Tie" from the list of extras.

```js
var hasNeckTie = false;
if (hasNeckTie = true) {
  document.getElementById("checkoutnecktie").innerHTML = "Neck Tie";
}
```

```html
<div class="three columns bear">
  <h3>Matching Tartan Scarf (£2.50)</h3>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" name="scarf" id="scarf" value="2.5" />
    <img src="Images/Scarft.png">
  </label>
  <p>Personalise your bear with a matching tartan scarf. It gets cold up here in Scotland, and this is the best way to keep your bear warm.</p>
</div>

<div id="checkoutnecktie"></div>
```

Any ideas why this code isn't running properly?

Comment: Firstly, `=` in the `if` condition should be `==`, however you have no element with `id="checkoutnecktie"` ... ?

Comment: The `=` operator doesn't check for equality, it's the assignment operator. For comparison, use `===`.

Comment: Also, `if(hasNeckTie = false)` should be `if(hasNeckTie == false)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem starts where you are using `=` instead of [`==`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) in your [`if`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) statement.

You are also trying to set the HTML value of an element which does not exist.
`document.getElementById("checkoutnecktie").innerHTML = "Neck Tie";`

You need to change `"checkoutnecktie"` to an element ID which exists.

Comment: Apologies. it does exist, I just didn't include it in my Snippet as I was wanting to focus more on the IF condition. I have don't the HTML value on other elements and it works fine, it's just the checkbox selection process I'm, trying to figure out

Answer (score 0):

You would need to hook an event to the checkbox.
You can do this with jQuery like so

```
$('#scarf').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('#checkoutnecktie').text('Neck tie');
    }
}
```

Also like the other answer states, set the text to an element that exists.